# I want a clarification about in Android

Tags: android

I am a .NET developer who is in the beginning stage in Android development. Please explain me the code below.

```
nine=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b9);
nine.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Initialize the button and set its click event.

Comment: Why don't you try some online tutorials related to Android development.Just Google it and you will get your answers.

Comment: Also "Please explain the code below" is not a question.

Comment: Hey chekc my answer, let me know if it solved your question otherwise I'll update it, but you must mark any answer as a correct! :D

Answer (score 3):

```
nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
```

Look for the view called b9, cast it to button, and assign it to your variable.

```
nine.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Add your class as a listener of clicks on that button if we are implementing the OnClickListener interface otherwise we have to create new OnClickListener using like this.

```
nine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    }
});
```

P.S: This is not the way to learn Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
nine=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b9);
```

It search the element by id (R.id.**b9**) and cast it to button and assign that value to the variable nine.

```
nine.setOnClickListener(this);
```

variable nine is button type variable so set the OnClickListener on this to fire some event after clicking on it.

and this activity must implement OnClickListener

```
public class a extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

}
```